# audit folder which group gives you access

Tags: windows, security, ntfs

https://www.online-tech-tips.com/windows-xp/how-to-track-and-monitor-who-and-when-someone-accesses-a-folder-on-your-computer/

i followed this guide to add auditing to a specific folder. I added "Everyone" to the audit users.

When i now change something on the folder (create a folder) and see activity in the windows event log.

But where can i read which group gave me access to the specific folder?
Is see stuff like this : D:(A;OICI;FA;;;WD) on Access Reason.

Is there some kind of cryptic translation of the "EveryOne" "Group"

What i need to know basically; Which users are using a specific directory and have access because they are in "EveryOne"

We want to remove "EveryOne" from a specific folder, but need to know which users are using the "group", so we can put them in a Different Group

Answer (score 0):

The above text is formatted using the Security Descriptor Definition Language (SDDL https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379567(v=vs.85).aspx). Refer https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374928(v=vs.85).aspx to decode your sddl string.

1. 'D:' stands for DACL is changed or created.
2. The number of parantheses pairs denotes number of the number access control entries added or modified.(in this case 1).
3. OICI - This indicates that the ACE applies to this folder, its files and its subfolders.
4. FA denotes what permission is actually provided (All Access).
5. Finally WD stands for 'Everyone'.

Also refer https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askds/2008/05/07/the-security-descriptor-definition-language-of-love-part-2/